# Best way to implements this kind of pattern in Java (Python sample inside)?

Tags: java, python, loops

i am still new to the Java language and libraries... i often use this kind of pattern in Python, and wonder how i should implement this one with Java.

i need to read a huge file line by line, with some kind of xml marking (i am producing the input, so i am sure that there will not be any ambiguity)

i want to iterate inside some parts of the huge file like the python code below :

(using the yield / python iterator pattern... is there any equivallent in Java? i really do like the `for item in my collection: yield something_about(many items)`)

what will be the best (java) way to implement this kind of behaviour ?

thx

**first EDIT:** BTW, i would have also be interested in the similar mapping between List and File that are available from a Python point of view when using file and [python list,] if of course possible with Java => answer : see Jeff Foster suggestion of using : Apache.IOUtils

```
def myAcc(instream, start, end):
    acc = []
    inside = False
    for line in instream:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith(start):
            inside = True
        if inside:
            acc.append(line)
        if line.startswith(end):
            if acc:
                yield acc
                acc = []
            inside = False


f = open("c:/test.acc.txt")

s = """<c>
<a>
this is a test
</a>
<b language="en" />
</c>
<c>
<a>
ceci est un test
</a>
<b language="fr" />
</c>
<c>
<a>
esta es una prueba
</a>
<b language="es" />
</c>"""

f = s.split("\n")   # here mimic for a input file...

print "Reading block from <c> tag!"
for buf in myAcc(f, "<c>", "</c>"):
    print buf # actually process this inner part... printing is for simplification
    print "-" * 10

print "Reading block from <a> tag!"
for buf in myAcc(f, "<a>", "</a>"):
    print buf  # actually process this inner part...
    print "-" * 10
```

OUTPUT :

```
Reading block from <c> tag!
['<c>', '<a>', 'this is a test', '</a>', '<b language="en" />', '</c>']
----------
['<c>', '<a>', 'ceci est un test', '</a>', '<b language="fr" />', '</c>']
----------
['<c>', '<a>', 'esta es una prueba', '</a>', '<b language="es" />', '</c>']
----------
Reading block from <a> tag!
['<a>', 'this is a test', '</a>']
----------
['<a>', 'ceci est un test', '</a>']
----------
['<a>', 'esta es una prueba', '</a>']
----------
```

so directly inspired by the answer of Jeff Foster below, here is a try to solve my trouble and do the same kind of thing than my python code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface WorkerThing { 
    public void doSomething(List<String> acc); 
} 

class ThatReadsLargeFiles { 
    public void readAHugeFile( BufferedReader input, String start, String end, WorkerThing action) throws IOException { 
        // TODO write some code to read through the file and store it in line 
        List<String> acc = new ArrayList<String> ();
        String line; 
        Boolean inside = false;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals(start)) {
                inside = true;
            }
            if (inside) {
                acc.add(line);
            }
            if (line.equals(end)) {
                if (acc != null && !acc.isEmpty()) { // well not sure if both are needed here...
                    // Here you are yielding control to something else
                    action.doSomething(acc);
                    //acc.clear(); // not sure how to empty/clear a list... maybe : List<String> acc = new ArrayList<String> (); is enough/faster?
                    acc = new ArrayList<String> (); // looks like this is the *right* way to go!
                }
                inside = false;
                // ending
            }
        } 
        input.close();
    } 
 }

public class YieldLikeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String path = "c:/test.acc.txt";

        File myFile = new File(path);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myFile), "UTF8"));
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path, "utf8"));

        new ThatReadsLargeFiles().readAHugeFile(in, "<a>", "</a>", new WorkerThing() {
                public void doSomething(List<String> acc) {
                    System.out.println(acc.toString());
                }
        });


    }

}
```

**second EDIT:** i was too fast accepting this answer, actually, i still miss and have a misunderstanding : i do not know how to get and keep trace of the content of `acc`at the @ most upper level (not inside the anonymous class). So that it can be used from the calling for something else than printing say for example instantiate a class, and do other processing... Yield allow this kind of usage, i do not see how i can adapt the proposed answer to have this behaviour. Sorry, my Python usage/sample was to simple.

so here is the answer derived from the Jeff Foster explanation for memorizing the acc:

```
class betweenWorker implements WorkerThing {

    private List<String> acc;

    public void process(List<String> acc) {
        this.acc = acc;
    }
    public List<String> getAcc() { return this.acc; }
}
```

Comment: I have reindented your code which was invalid before. I hope I got it right. (This is why you should use spaces, not tabs for indentation, and most importantly, never mix the two)

Comment: thank you ! yes, i've missed this when pasting in another text editor just to insert spaces for pasting here so the code can be seen as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't support something like the `yield`, but you can achieve the same sort of thing by creating an interface that encapsulates the action that you'll perform on the individual lines.

```
interface WorkerThing {
  void doSomething(string lineOfText);
}

class ThatReadsLargeFiles {
    public void readAHugeFile(WorkerThing actions) {
        // TODO write some code to read through the file and store it in line

        // Here you are yielding control to something else
        action.doSomething(line);
    }
 }
```

When you use it you can use anonymous interface implementations to make things slightly more bearable.

```
new ThatReadsLargeFiles().readAHugeFile(new WorkerThing() {
    void doSomething(string text) {
        System.out.println(text); 
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you, edited my question to replicate your answer that help me builiding a working code. BTW Can it be possible to map File and List<String>? So it can be done generic like with Python?

Comment: Apache.IOUtils can provide helper methods to turn a file into a List<string>, but there's no generic (i.e. built into the language) way to do it.

Comment: thank you! btw, i actually have another trouble with this solution, that is from my understanding, how could i assign the `acc` inside the `doSomething` to a var of the upper level? So that it can be used in the upper call? or may be should i ask another SO question? Best regards

Comment: You could make the class not anonymous and capture the variable afterwards (e.g. MyWorkerThing workerThing = new MyWorkerThing(); new ThatReadsLargeFiles(workerThing); string myAcc = workerThing.acc;

Comment: ok, i get it. i am going to edit my question to put a working example answer for this part. BTW i had difficulties to have it work, because of the `acc.clear()` in my code that was clearing everything, i do not really get why... but it looks like reseting acc must be better done with `acc = new ArrayList<String> ();`...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood Python code and your task correctly, this can be accomplished in the following way:

```
// callback representing function to be invoked on String array
public interface Callback {
    void process(List<String> lines);
}

public void processFile(final String path, final String start, final String end, final Callback callback) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean inside = false;

        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith(start)) {
                inside = true;
            }

            if(inside) {
                lines.add(line);
            }

            if(line.startsWith(end)) {
                inside = false;
                callback.process(lines);
                lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
        }
    // following is just boilerplate to correctly close readers
    } catch(final IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch(final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then somewhere in your code you can invoke this method like here:

```
// ...
// creating instance of class implementing Callback interface (this is called 'anonymous' class in Java)
final Callback myCallback = new Callback() {
    public void process(List<String> lines) {
        for(String line : lines) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
};
processFile("path/to/file", "<c>", "</c>", myCallback);
processFile("path/to/file", "<a>", "</a>", myCallback);
// ...
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: thank you a lot Yura, i am sorry, i have accepted Jeff Foster's answer because he was first, but you were faster than me to rewrite te correct piece of code! so up vote for yours too.